# Passing data from client vs fetching it on server side

Tags: rest, design-patterns

I have a REST API which expects few parameters and I am expecting the caller of this API to pass this information in the body. For example:- my API expects userId, first name, last name.

The developer on the client side argues that he wouldn't be sending first name and last name and my API should make another call internally to fetch this information based on user id from some other API.

I understand that this could be helpful in some scenarios but I don't think it would be always a good idea that service code makes additional call to fetch additional information which is already available to client. Want to know where should I draw the line?

Comment: It really depends on what your API is doing.  I'm assuming that the user ID is a reference to a user in a database somewhere.  Is it imperative that the first and lastname passed to your API match the first and lastname of the user in the database?  If so, then you should be fetching that information yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one service has to make a request to another service *and block until it receives a response*, then the first service can't work without the other service. This creates coupling, which is perhaps the greatest problem in software development.

In the context of one service depending on another, this coupling effectively turns two services into one. You no longer have two services, you have a single, distributed ball of mud.

It's usually worthwhile avoiding this situation, but it depends on circumstances. The OP doesn't supply enough details to go further than that, but I'd be wary of introducing coupling if it's possible to avoid it.

Thus, I'd insist that the client supplies the required data, unless there are clear indications that this is somehow not practical.